# Pycharm multiple int(input())'s returns ValueError, but works in other IDE's

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, pycharm

I have recently downloaded the Pycharm IDE. I have tried using the simple code:

```
a = int(input("Enter a number:"))
b = int(input("Enter another number:"))
```

Pycharm asks for a number, and I enter 6.

```
Enter a number:6
```

Then Pycharm sends this:

```
Enter another number:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/justi/comp-sci_11_final/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    b = int(input("Enter another number:"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It seems like it is not letting me input another value, as the string in the error is empty, and the error comes from "b = int(input())" but I am not sure why.

I am using python 3.7, and Pycharm 2018.3. It works perfectly fine in repl.it, so it seems that Pycharm is the guilty party.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
Moving it to a new program worked, but I have experienced the issue again afterwards. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: have you tried the solutions posted in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829176/input-in-python-does-not-wait-for-my-input-in-pycharm ?

Comment: I did try the first and last ones, but somehow I missed moving it to a new file. That fixed the problem. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Oh ok, perfect :)

Comment: I am getting the erreor again. I can fix it, but it is kind of annoying. Does anyone know a way to fix or prevent this from happening?

Comment: it's probably better if you update/edit the question, maybe someone knows it