# Can someone help me understand why I keep getting a keyboard interrupt error?

Tags: pycharm

Hi im working on a school assignment using Pycharm
code goes as:

```
import datetime
name = input("What is your name?  Adam")
age = int(input("How old are you? 32"))
year = datetime.datetime.now().year
print("Hello! Adam you were born in" + str((year - age)))
```

when I run the code I keep getting this error

```
C:\Users\akuli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe             C:\Users\akuli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\derp.der.py 
AdamTraceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\akuli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\derp.der.py", line 1, in     <module>
name = input('Adam')
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen codecs>", line 319, in decode KeyboardInterrupt
```

I have tried to change the code several times to only slowly start to lose my mind any help out there?

I have tried to rewrite my code several times just to keep getting the same result. when I run the module it seems like it just stops at the first line instead of running through them all

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt happens if you press ctrl+c. Try running the code without pycharm, and seeing if anything different happens.

Comment: Your expectation of what `input` does may be wrong. The argument to `input` is a string which is displayed to the user; it then waits for the user to type a response. If you don't do that and instead break out with ctrl-C, you get a KeyboardInterrupt. Your code looks like you expect the _answer_ to be picked up from the code, but that's not how it works. (Also, the code in the traceback is different from the code you are asking about, though I suppose we can guess what's going on anyway.)

Comment: ok so from what I know input is just inputting the data into the string is it not? or is there something I'm missing there? also I never pressed ctrl+C to break the line. so why would I be getting the keyboard interrupt is my question or as to why it never makes it past the first line. and yes the expectation I had is like with R where the inputs just automatically input themselves and the code still runs through is it not like that?

Comment: No, `input` waits for the user to type something. Running `result = input("type a number: ")` will display `type a number: ` and wait for you to do that; whatever you type in (and press Enter) will be assigned to `result`. It's really not clear what you mean by "the inputs just automatically input themselves"; where would these inputs come from? What do you hope this code should actually accomplish?

Comment: PyCharm might be a contributing complication here because running code within an IDE sometimes hides these details behind the IDE itself. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829176/input-in-python-does-not-wait-for-my-input-in-pycharm

Comment: `name = "Adam"; age = 32` would assign these variables without requiring interaction by the user.

Comment: (Of course, the result your program prints will be incorrect for someone whose birthday is later in the current year.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a blank line in the terminal, but it is waiting for you to enter a value to read. Enter value: