# How do I make a python shell start running

Tags: python

[image]

I wrote a program in my editor and clicked run(F5).   Afterwards, in the python shell, I keyed in the desired inputs.  What should i do next to make it start running?   Attached picture is python editor and python shell.

Thanks!

Comment: *What should i do next to make it start running?* ca you explain ?

Comment: Yeah, basically, I don't know what I need to do to indicate to the program that I have already put in all the inputs. I want the program to start running with these input but I can't find any method of making it run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiline input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user)

Comment: Pressing enter will just create another row of input.    LOL

Comment: You should be using input/raw_input, no one uses stdin.read

Comment: Well, stdin.read appears to me as more convenient as I can deal with any data with just the same code. Whereas, input/raw_input needs to loop through.

Comment: Yeah, it seems really convenient when you can't get it to stop taking input.

Comment: You can @JJJ you just use CTRL-D - super intuitive for the user

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL-D to stop entering new sys.stdin.read() input. Also don't use this.

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/whats-the-difference-between-sysstdinread-and-input