# How to take several lines as input in python?

Tags: python, input

I know the easiest way to take input in python is with the function `input()` .

However, what if I have to take several numbers on separate lines at once and add them up.

Example input:

```
2
3
1
4
```

How can I read this input into a list?

I am a beginner in python so please any advice is appreciated

Comment: Will the input be passed together? Or will it be added as separate inputs? You can use `input().split('\n')` otherwise `x1 = input()`, `x2 = input` etc..

Comment: Maybe it can helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
numbers_list = []
for i in range(number_of_needs):
    n = input()
    number_list.append(n)
```

or you can use `while` if you don't know the count.

```
numbers_list = []
while True:
    n = input()
    if n == 'q':
        break
    number_list.append(n)
```

in this case, it breaks when user inputs `q`.

also, note that `n`s are String you can use `int()` to convert them to an integer.