# how to take multi line string input from user in python,without breaking the input

Tags: python, python-3.x

we face the problem while taking multi-line input for strings in python.

```
s=str(input("enter string"))
```

when i enter the input 
for suppose let us assume that i entered my input as:

```
hello friends!!
good morning
```

when i try to print this i get only `'hello friends!!'`

is there any other code to take until i press a special symbol to tell to compiler that it is EOF of my input
like in c we have code like `scanf("%[^~]",str);`
it takes the input until we press `"~"` symbol.

like this do we have any special operations in python.

expected output of above program is

```
hello friends!! good morning
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked here many times. Please use the search function or click here: [How to get multiline input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user)

tldr:

```
import sys
msg = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Comment: how can say we have reached the EOF to system

Comment: @pavankumar That depends on your system and terminal you are using. Usually it's a simple key combination like shift+return.