# How to create a multi-line input in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, multiline

Is it possible to create an input field with multiple lines?
Or is the single string input the only option at this time?
(`#@param {type:"string"}`)

We want to make an input field with multiple rows, for example a list of string values.

Comment: Try this solution, it's perfrect https://stackoverflow.com/a/38223253

Comment: I wouldn't say using `input` is perfect, since you'd need to re-input everything each run of the cell.