# Python: for loop breaks when encountering newline

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I've written a small script to strip "`" out of multi-line SQL queries, and every time the loop comes to the end of a line, it breaks. below is the code, and what im inserting:

```
inp = input('Enter Query: ')

for s in inp:
    if s != '`':
        print(s, end = '')
```

input is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Employees` (
  `Employees_PK` INT NOT NULL,
  `Employee_L_NAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Employee_F_NAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Employees_PHONE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Employee_EMAIL` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Employee_HIRE_DATE` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Employee_MANAGED_BY` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Employees_PK`))
```

So the problem is that the for loop breaks after one line, and only outputs this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.Employees (
```

Any way to get around this? its not essential to preserve the structure (indents, etc.), but it would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Because, `input()` takes only one line.

You can notice that just add a simple `print()` right after `input()`

```py
inp = input('Enter Query: ')

print('input check:', inp)

for s in inp:
    if s != '`':
        print(s, end = '')


"""
<Output>
input check: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Employees` (
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.Employees (
"""
```

So, if you want to get input multiple lines, change like this:

```py
print("Enter Query: ", end='')

# Get input until have line of texts.
while True:
    inp = input()

    if not inp:
        break

    for s in inp:
        if s != '`':
            print(s, end='')
```

Please, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239138/7110084