# How do I make python take multiple horizontal lines of numerical input and output the same lines?

Tags: python

I am asking the user to input some ID numbers, but they will only be able to paste them into the program horizontally.

```
print("Please cut and paste your ID numbers:")

User input:
12345
54321
99999
```

I want python to perform this function on all the numbers:

```
print ('s'+(user input)+'@'+'students.xisd.org')
```

This is the output that I want:

```
s12345@student.xisd.org
s54321@student.xisd.org
s99999@student.xisd.org
```

I don't know how to allow python to accept several lines of horizontal input and give the same outputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question - [Taking multi line input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239138/10145519). 

And also take care of what prune said.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Reading input from a line is well-documented in many tutorials; we expect you to work through those before posting here.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Comment: Yes. Anywhere from 12 to 20 seven digit numbers.

Comment: `print (f"s{input()}@students.xisd.org")`

Comment: @anuragal That's just a mistake from OP. If a user pastes the numbers horizontally, the example input by OP should have been space separated not '\n' separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. You will have to press enter twice to indicate the end of the input (precisely to break out of while loop).

```
numbers = []

while True:
    num = input()
    if num:
        numbers.append(num)
    else:
        break
    
for num in numbers:
    print('s' + num + '@students.xisd.org')
```

Answer (score 1):

When a newline character is to be included as part of the string, it can no longer serve the purpose of signaling the end of input. You could try the following:

```
import sys
multiline_str = sys.stdin.read()
```

Enter ctrl+z on a blank line to signal the end of input.