# How to print one line every two lines of a string?

Tags: python

Here is what I've tried :

```
i = 1
text = str(input())
for i in range(nbLignes):
   if i % 2 != 0:
      print(text)
```

I couldn't find any answer else where

Comment: Hello, please can you describe what you mean by one line?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print every second line?

Comment: Best show some some sample input and desired output.

Comment: Please produce a [mre]

Comment: also, can you tell what is `nbLignes`, `text` in the code ?

Comment: Also, you cannot really get mulitple lines with a single `input()` call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have some text (with new lines) you can print every second line by splitting the str by lines and then use index slicing to pick only every second line starting from index 1

```py
text = """line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7"""


for line in text.splitlines()[1::2]:
    print(line)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
line 2
line 4
line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the input every every other time in the range.
If so, then most of your code is correct. Add just one line:

```
i += 1
```

after the if statement. This adds 1 to i, so in the next loop it becomes 2 and so on. Since you didn't add to i, i's value remained 1 and so didn't print.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote and mark this answer as correct. Thank you!