# how can i do multiple lines of an input field? PYTHON

Tags: python, user-input

**python**

```
input(write some text: )
```

what i want it to output is:

```
write some text: it was a good day
today as i went to a park
```

then press enter button twice to go on to the other lines of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get multiline input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
print("enter 'quit' at end of your text")
print("type your text here")
# declare variable to strore string
text = ""
stop_word = "quit"
while True:
    line = input()
    if line.strip() == stop_word:
        break
    # \n is new line, %s is string formatting
    # str.strip() will remove any whitespace that is at start or end
    text += "%s\n" % line.strip()
print(text)
```

if you want use **3 blank lines** as stop word:

```py
print("Please enter 3 blank lines to terminate")
print("type your text here")
# declare variable to strore string
text = ""
stop_word = "quit"
counter = 0
while True:
    line = input()
    if line.strip() == '':
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            break
    # \n is new line, %s is string formatting
    # str.strip() will remove any whitespace that is at start or end
    text += "%s\n" % line.strip()
print(text)
```

for the result, if you want to get rid of blank lines:

```py
print("Please enter 3 blank lines to terminate")
print("type your text here")
# declare variable to strore string
text = ""
stop_word = "quit"
counter = 0
while True:
    line = input()
    if line.strip() == '':
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            # break terminates while loop
            break
        # continue go to start of while loop
        continue
    # \n is new line, %s is string formatting
    # str.strip() will remove any whitespace that is at start or end
    text += "%s\n" % line.strip()
print(text)
```

Comment: how can i change it to do 3 lines and then go onto the next code?

Comment: i more question, in line variable when the user does the input it will include the 3 lines that don't induce any thing. anyway to change that without changing the t enters in the input field?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sys.stdin.readlines to read multiple lines, and break by using ctrl + z (on windows) / ctrl + d.

```
import sys

msg = sys.stdin.readlines()
```