# Python, how to take multi line string with new lines as input from user?

Tags: python

I have an input in this format

```
someemailadress@outlook.com
someotheremail@outlook.com
nextemail@gmail.com
```

So I want to get this input from user so when I get the input by:

```
emails = input("Provide emails")
```

User just could copy and paste the whole lists of email given one under one, seperarted by new line into this variable so then I can use .splitlines() to get the e-mail to seperate spaces so I can use them for something. For whatever reason it doesn't want to accept such input, when I try to give as little as two e-mail, one after the other, seperated by new line. I get following error

```
Provide emailsomeemailadress@outlook.com
someotheremail@outlook.com
invoice.nl5a@philips.com
> 
> someemailadress@outlook.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'someemailadress' is not defined
```

why is happening?

Comment: `while (email := input()): emails.append(email)`

Comment: I doesn't do anything, just get stuck in eternal loop and I want to take input in one go, copy paste enter and go, not give every e-mail separately

Comment: It does append every line into a list `emails` until empty string will be passed. So paste all emails and press "Enter".

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user