# python click prompt multiline

Tags: python, prompt

I'm using [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) to create a CLI tool and need to prompt for a JSON payload. Is there a way to prompt for multiple lines using the following (or any other API)?

```
click.prompt(
    "Payload",
    type=click.STRING
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user ? I tried the second example of the accepted answer and it worked just as you need it (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: I saw this one yes. Was wondering if something was available in the click library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [Click `edit` API](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.edit). Like it says in its documentation [here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/utils/#launching-editors):

> This is very useful for asking users for multi-line input.