# Loop through unlimited multiline input

Tags: python, input, multiline

Imagine **unlimited** multiline input with some URL addresses, for example:

[image: inputed URL addresses in PyCharm]

**How would you get that addresses from the input separately?**

Following was close, but actually not helping:

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break
text = '\n'.join(lines)
```

source: [How to get multiline input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239092/how-to-get-multiline-input-from-user)

And other advices I consider completely useless: https://python.plainenglish.io/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python-3-6cbe02d03a95

Comment: what is the problem? what is the question?

Comment: Just read again.

Comment: Either you do the processing of lines (per line) inside the loop, or you have to provide some way for the user to terminate the input. How would you otherwise know when to stop reading input?

Comment: "Following was close, but actually not helping" ...in what way?  are you able to explain what you actually want?

Comment: I want get all URL links from the input.

Comment: @pavel What is the source of input? Is it interactive, streamed or something else?

Comment: @Stuart just user's copy and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, this may help:

```
lines = []
try:
    while line := input():
        lines.append(line)
except EOFError:
    pass
print(lines)
```

This will handle both interactive and redirected input (stdin)

Comment: The problem is, that while loop will start over again with new input request.

Comment: This works exactly as requested. You could copy and paste, or enter free text. Not sure what issue you are having here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function you could use:

```
import sys
sys.stdin.read()
```

But I'm not sure this is a great idea because it won't know when to stop reading. The traditional `input()` function will detect a `\n` symbol via the return key, then end input.

I think looping would be the best way forward.

Like:

```
urls = ''

while True:
    url = input()
    
    if url:
        urls += url + '\n'
    else:
        break
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: The problem is, that while loop will start over again with new input request.

Comment: No. Once it detects an empty lines IE just press enter twice when you’re done, then it will exit out of the input.